# Running an Arduino sketch with Fritzing

Tags: embedded, arduino, avr-gcc

I am trying to learn programming on hardware, and have ordered an [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) for that. While I wait for it to be delivered, I started to poke around and came across [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/). I am able to attach an LED to the microcontroller. My problem is this:

Fritzing comes with an IDE that can be used to write code for the Arduino and [PICAXE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PICAXE) microcontrollers. Having written the code to blink the LED on an Arduino, I am unable to compile it and attach it to the schematic I have made. How do I do that? The page *[Experimental program window](http://fritzing.org/news/experimental-program-window/)*  is not really helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I work on the Fritzing team. Picaxe programming does work in Fritzing, but currently Arduino programming does not--the long story is that there is no easy shell command for launching the Arduino compiler and uploader.

You can edit programs for the Arduino in Fritzing, but to run them you still have to use the Arduino IDE. We should make it clearer that Arduino programming is not full available in Fritzing.

Comment: I just downloaded Fritzing, wrote my code, tried to run it, searched like half an hour for a play-button, and finally found this post. If it´s just another software to layout electronic parts, why all that aruino buzzwording?

Answer (score 3):

It is currently not possible to simulate an Arduino circuit with `Fritzing`. Neither are there any plans to simulate Arduino.

Check this link:
http://fritzing.org/forum/thread/3/